# Не подтягиваются стили css

Tags: html, css, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Страница не подтягивает css и выдает много ошибок

```
Refused to apply style from '<URL>' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

В чем проблема ?

HTML страница :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head th:include="layout :: headerFragment">
    <title id="pageTitle">Login</title>

</head>
<body>
<div th:insert="layout :: headerFragment"></div>
<div class="row">
    <form class="col mx-auto" th:action="@{/login}" th:method="post">
        <div class="mt-10">
            <input type="text" id="user_id" name="username" placeholder="Username" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''"
                   onblur="this.placeholder = 'Username'" required class="single-input">
        </div>
        <div class="mt-10">
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Username" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''"
                   onblur="this.placeholder = 'Username'" required class="single-input">
        </div>

        <section class="button-area">
            <div class="container border-top-generic">
                <div class="button-group-area mt-40">
                    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" id="sign-btn">sign in</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </form>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thymeleaf config :

```
  @Bean
    @Primary
    public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        final SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setApplicationContext(this.applicationContext);
        templateResolver.setPrefix("classpath:/templates/");
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        templateResolver.setOrder(2);
        templateResolver.setCacheable(true);
        return templateResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("templateEngine")
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        final SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
        templateEngine.setEnableSpringELCompiler(true);
        return templateEngine;
    }

    @Bean
    public ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver() {
        final ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        return viewResolver;
    }
```

Update :

```
<head th:fragment="headerFragment">
    <!-- Mobile Specific Meta -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- Favicon-->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" th:href="@{/img/fav.png}">
    <!-- Author Meta -->
    <meta name="author" content="codepixer">
    <!-- Meta Description -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <!-- Meta Keyword -->
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
    <!-- meta character set -->
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <!-- Site Title -->
    <title th:include=":: #pageTitle">Layout Generic Title</title>

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:100,200,400,300,500,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--
    CSS
    ============================================= -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/linearicons.css}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/font-awesome.min.css}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/bootstrap.css}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/magnific-popup.css}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/nice-select.css}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/hexagons.min.css}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/animate.min.css}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/owl.carousel.css}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/main.css}">
</head>
```

Comment: mime css описывается как 'text/css', предполагаю, что в этом проблема)

Comment: Тимур Жумашев, как исправить ?

Comment: Решение, что вы используете, мне не знакомо. Подключение стилей идёт между тегами <head> ... </head>, т.е. я указал на возможную причину. В вашем коде я не вижу подключения стилей, быть может, подключение идёт в каких-либо иных файлах.

Comment: Тимур Жумашев,обновил вопрос, добавил подключения стилей с другого файла.